# What's this meaning in yacc?

Tags: yacc

```
%right <code> UNARY PLUSPLUS MINUSMINUS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Precedence-Decl) will help.
This declaration specifies that the tokens `UNARY` `PLUSPLUS` `MINUSMINUS` are
right associative.
`<code>` indicates the type of the semantic value of these tokens.
In this case, I presume an `union` like the following is declared in the
source code:

```
%union {
  ...
  <some-type> code;
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have shift/reduce warnings it means that there is a point when the parser could either add a token onto the stack or reduce it using some rule. By default it chooses to "shift", this tells it to reduce that token whenever possible instead.

Generally, unless you have a really weird grammer, the default of it shifting is what you want to happen (I can't think of any instance where I would want it to reduce, but its there for a reason so...).

Generally you just want to say %left instead for certain tokens, just for the sake of removing the shift/reduce warnings